# Can I do remote live preview using Adobe Brackets?

Tags: adobe-brackets, live-preview

Here's my situation: I have two computers on my desk and I would like to use one of them to develop webpages and use another to do a live preview.

Is there an option in Brackets that I can do this? I tried to access the intranet ip address with the port number appearing in the URL when I'm doing a live preview using a local machine, but it cannot be accessed.

Comment: It is in fact NOT possible YET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to use Live Preview on different machines that share the same local network since Release Brackets 1.1. To do this, open your preference file via `Debug > Open Preferences File` and insert the following directive: `livedev.multibrowser: true`. Note that you may have to add a trailing comma. For more information, see https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/Live-Preview-Multibrowser

Comment: Downvoting As this does not work as @Lesly mentioned. This setting is for the live-reload to work with multiple browsers simultaneously, not to expose the server to the local network.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no remote (LAN) live preview in Brackets and there are open issues on Github for the feature request. ([Here's one for example](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/6424))

The `livedev.multibrowser` option described in the currently accepted answer opens live preview to multiple browsers *on the same machine* but does not allow access from anything other than localhost.

Here's a workaround that I've been using in the meantime:

Make a standard local web server (with Node/Apache/IIS/whatever) and install and run [LiveReload](http://livereload.com/) on your dev machine for your project. On the remote machine(s) install the [LiveReload browser extension](http://livereload.com/extensions/), visit your site and turn on the LiveReload plugin. You don't get the instant (saveless) updates of the Brackets live preview, but the page will auto-refresh on remote machines when you save any files inside your project.